# Where to download the Cycles render engine?

Tags: 3d, blender

I've installed Blender from Software Center, but it doesn't contain the **Cycles render** engine by default. Is it a different package or do I need to download Blender from a PPA?

Comment: In Software Center isn't newest version of blender. ;)

Comment: can you suggest a good PPA?

Comment: **ppa:irie/blender** - https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender

Comment: the perfect one so far. Thank you. how do I mark it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this ppa - **ppa:irie/blender** @ https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender.